# unable to instantiate activity component info, getting runtime exception and java.lang.nullpointer exception

Tags: java, android

I am doing to develop an app that perform **walkie talkie** function over **WiFi direct**.
I create walkietalkiefunction activity that that record audio using **media recorder thread** class and send it to client using RTP socket(**Sendersocket class**).I tried to start this activity from fragment. I tried many times and I found the error (Runtime exception:Unable to in instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp/com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp.WalkieTalkieFunction}: java.lang.NullPointerException). so pls help me? I can't  solve it. do you have an idea how to fix this problem?

```
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity componentInfo{com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp/com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp.WalkieTalkieFunction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp.WalkieTalkieFunction.<init>(WalkieTalkieFunction.java:26)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at  java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-09 08:40:09.361: E/AndroidRuntime(1301):     ... 11 more
```

Here is code :
                package com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp;

```
            import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pDevice;
            import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pInfo;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Context;
            import android.database.Cursor;
            import android.view.Menu;
            import android.view.View;
            import android.widget.EditText;
            import android.widget.ImageButton;

            public class WalkieTalkieFunction extends Activity {

                private WifiP2pDevice device =null;
                private WifiP2pInfo info =null;
                private FreqManager frqman =new FreqManager();
                private DeviceListFragment dlf=null;
                //Context context =null;
                //Object sstmonitor =new Object();

                Object mrtmonitor=new Object();

                String host = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();

                @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    
    {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkie_talkie_function);


    ImageButton recorder1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.recorderbtn);
    recorder1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


      SocketSenderThread sst =new SocketSenderThread(8988,device.deviceAddress, 
                                                  sstmonitor);

        EditText edtxt1= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.wtflbl1);

            if(frqman.isInSameGroup
                                     (dlf.getSelectedItemPosition()))
                      {
        MediaRecorderThread mrt =new MediaRecorderThread(host, 
                         mrtmonitor);
                                   mrt.run();
                        edtxt1.setText("now recording");
                                  // sst.init();
                                   //sst.run();
                                 }                          
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
           public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.
            activity_walkie_talkie_function, menu);
                    return true;
                }

            }

enter code here
        package com.walkietakli2.android.mcomp;

        import java.io.File;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.net.DatagramSocket;
        import java.net.InetAddress;
        import java.net.SocketException;
        import java.net.UnknownHostException;

        import android.os.Environment;
        import android.util.Log;


        public class SocketSenderThread implements Runnable{

     public SocketSenderThread(int dport,
        String daddr, Object ssMonitor) {
    super();        
    this.daddr = daddr;
    this.dport = dport;
    ss_monitor = ssMonitor;


    init();
    }

   private void init()
   {
    DatagramSocket src_socket = null;
    try {
         src_socket = new DatagramSocket();         

 Log.i(TAG, "init: dest addr"+InetAddress.getByName(daddr)+" port: "+dport);
 rtp_socket = new RtpSocket(src_socket,   InetAddress.getByName(daddr),dport);
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {            
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Socket cannot be opened");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private InputStream audio_input;
private String daddr;
private int dport;


private static final String TAG = "WalkieTalkieEngine";

public static boolean all_files_sent = true;

RtpSocket rtp_socket = null;

Object ss_monitor = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {
    int sample_rate = 8000;
    int sample_size = 1;
    int frame_size = Constants.PKT_SIZE;
    int payload_type = 0;       
    boolean running = true;
    int last_file_sent = 0;
    int num_files = 0;

    int frame_rate = sample_rate/(frame_size/sample_size);



    while(running)
    {
        if(all_files_sent)
        {
            synchronized(ss_monitor)
            {
                try{
                    Log.i(TAG, "Waiting for notif");
                    ss_monitor.wait();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){}
                num_files = MediaRecorderThread.max_file_num;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Got Notif");
        }

        // create # of streams and set that to audio_input
        for (int i = last_file_sent; i < num_files; i++) 
        {
            String path = null;
            try {
                Integer file_num = new Integer(i+1);
            path =Environment.getExternalStorageState().
               toString()+file_num.toString()+".3gp";
                audio_input = new FileInputStream(path);
                payload_type = i+1;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {                    
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (audio_input==null) 
                return;

            Log.e(TAG, "Trying to to send RTP packet from File"+path);

            byte[] buffer=new byte[frame_size+12];
            RtpPacket rtp_packet=new RtpPacket(buffer,0);
            rtp_packet.setPayloadType(payload_type);      
            int seqn=0;
            long time=0;
            long byte_rate=frame_rate*frame_size;

            boolean reading=true;

            Log.i(TAG, "Reading blocks of "+(buffer.length-12)+" bytes");
            while(reading)
            {
                int num=0;
                try {
                num = audio_input.read(buffer,12,buffer.length-12);
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Number of blocks read: "+num);
                if(num > 0)
                {
                    rtp_packet.setSequenceNumber(seqn++);
                       rtp_packet.setTimestamp(time);
                       rtp_packet.setPayloadLength(num);



                       try {
                        rtp_socket.send(rtp_packet);
            Log.i(TAG, "Sent packet of size: "+rtp_packet.getLength());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Send failure");
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                       long frame_time=(num*1000)/byte_rate;
                       time+=frame_time;

                 try {  Thread.sleep(frame_time);  } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
                else
                {
                    reading=false;
                    Log.i(TAG, "Error reading from InputStream");
                }
            }//end while reading
        File fileToDelete =new File(path);
            fileToDelete.delete();
            last_file_sent++;
        } // end-for

        all_files_sent =  true;
    } // end-while running
    }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is:

```
private WifiP2pInfo info =null;
...
String host = info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress();
```

You try to access `info.groupOwnerAddress` when `info` is null.
You must instantiate `info` before trying to access it.

Try using: `private WifiP2pInfo info = new WifiP2pInfo();`

Comment: First I appreciate your mindful help. Next I'd like to tell you as I am not successful making the modification you mentioned for me.I can't find out the error. there is init() function in socketsenderthread class would it be a problem? Please help me.the aim is to transfer audio by recording using media recorder and sending through socket to client that exist on connection of wifi direct. the app can make connection but can't record and transfer audio data. please  help me!

Comment: I dont know how to explain it better. The problem is exactly as I pointed out. You need to create `info` object (using new or getting it somehow) before accessing it.

Comment: You can check this example http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.0.1_r1/com/example/android/wifidirect/DeviceDetailFragment.java

Comment: See that the set this.info = info on line 143, and only after this line, line 133 (info.groupOwnerAddress) can be called, because at this point info is not null anymore.